# Passing dynamic values to JSP Taglib using Spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, taglib

I need to pass a dynamic value to a custom taglib. Eg.

```
<ibe:I18N baseName="msg" key="dynamic value"/>
```

How do I pass the dynamic value?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [EL](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html): `key="${key}"`. You would need to allow expressions in taglib attributes by specifying `<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>` in the `.tld` file.